# Gettin error in SQL Server while finding out max age in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

We can try to get max age simply by using

```
SELECT TOP 1 age FROM Head1 ORDER BY Age DESC
```

But I've tried using while loop in SQL Server

**code**

```
declare @a int, @m int, @maxo int;
set @maxo = 0;
while(@a<10)
begin
    select name, @m = age from head1 where ID = @a;
    if @m>@maxo
       @maxo = @m;
    set @a=@a+1;
end
print @maxo
```

**error**

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>    A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>    Incorrect syntax near '@maxo'.

I am sort of stuck here. Please help guys.....

Comment: Refer this: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-141.aspx

Comment: Glad you found all the answers helpful! You can only give *one* the *accepted* mark  however. Since the one answer you picked as *accepted* last was also a duplicate post, I deleted that one giving you another chance at picking just *one* post as the one that helped you the most. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @a int, @m int, @maxo int 
declare @name NVARCHAR(100)
set @maxo = 0;
while(@a<10)
begin
    select @name = name, @m = age from head1 where ID = @a;
     if @m>@maxo
       SET @maxo = @m;
       set @a=@a+1;
END
PRINT @name +  ',' + CAST(@maxo AS NVARCHAR(50))
```

**ALTERNATE WAY IS**

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM Header1 WHERE Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM Header1)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues:

**Issue 1:**

The error which you are getting is self explanatory ie, you cant select the column while you are assigning the values to the variable.

You can resolve it like this:

```
select @name = name, @m = age from head1 where ID = @a;
```

**Issue 2:**

In this I dont think you need that query at all to find the max age from your table. You can simply use max() function to find the max age from your table like this

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM Head1 WHERE Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM Head1)
```

Using a loop is inefficient as well as it will create a performance bottleneck if your table is huge.

Answer (score 3):

Exception text is self-explanatory.

Since you can't retrieve `name` in the same statement where you're assigning `@m` (and actually you're not using this `name` anywhere - so it looks you don't need it), you have to change this line

```
select name, @m = age from head1 where ID = @a;
```

to

```
select @m = age from head1 where ID = @a;
```

Or, if you really need some name, it should be assigned to some variable too, not only selected:

```
select @n = name, @m = age from head1 where ID = @a;
```

But in general this will not work, since there can be multiple records in `head1` meets condition `ID = @a`. Assigning value to variable will only work if query returns only single row.

Note - using loop is **very** unefficient way of finding max value.

Answer (score 2):

At first I should ask you about `(@a<10)` that it should be always `10`?, And I think it is count of rows of your table that you take it like this:

```
DECLARE @rows bigint
SET @rows = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM head1)
```

Then use it ; `(@a < @rows)`.

---

Now the second problem is that you use `ID = @a` that is an invalid clause for deleted rows in your table or gaps. For solving this with using a kind of that clause you should find a `max(ID)` again and again.

---

I can just suggest you to use this query, But without `WHILE`:

```
DECLARE @max int
SET @max = 0

SELECT @max = CASE WHEN @max < age THEN age ELSE @max END
FROM head1
```

If you want to use `WHILE` in your way, you need a `ROW_NUMBER()` field like this in your code:

```
SET @m = (SELECT h1.age 
          FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY head1.age) AS rn 
                FROM head1) h1 
          WHERE h1.rn = @a;
```

instead of

```
select name, @m = age from head1 where ID = @a;
```